# jQuery Isotope: Empty slots found above 100% width block when introduced

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm intending to cater for blocks of fixed height and different width: 25%, 50%, 75% and 100%.
Everything seems okay until a 100% width block is introduced in. It seems that the empty spaces above the 100% width block are not filled up. Does isotope jquery factor in such use case?
I'm currently using masonry for layout mode.

Are there any kind souls out there who can help me in this issue?